# Angular component initialization - Is there a way to do conditional properties?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular component that is used to display a lot of different stuff. Think of it as a pop up window.

```
<my-component 
 [headLine]="data.headLine"
 [text]="data.text">
</my-component>
```

In some cases, there will be an image included as well. "my-component" has an optional "image" property, that is used in these cases. If an image is used, "my-component" has an output event that triggers when the image is loaded:

```
<my-component 
 [headLine]="data.headLine"
 [text]="data.text"
 [image]="data.img"
 (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded($event)">
</my-component>
```

As I need a container component now that initializes both of these "my-component" instances, I'm kind of locked into doing something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data.img; else noImage">
  <my-component 
   [headLine]="data.headLine"
   [text]="data.text"
   [image]="data.img"
   (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded($event)">
  </my-component>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noImage>
  <my-component 
   [headLine]="data.headLine"
   [text]="data.text">
  </my-component>
</ng-template>
```

I was wondering, if there's a way to achieve the same, in less lines of code? So something like saying the "imageLoaded" event should only be tracked, if "data.img" is present.

I guess my example wasn't describing the scenario that well - I don't have access to modifying the "imageLoaded" event, as this is from an external library.

So I guess the scenario I'm looking for is something like:

```
<my-component 
  [headLine]="data.headLine"
  [text]="data.text"

** ngIf="data.img" **
  [image]="data.img"
  (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded($event)"
** end of ngIf **
>
</my-component>
```

As far as I know, it's not possible to add conditionals like this in templates, but it's more of what I'm looking for.

Comment: What's the output of the ```imageLoaded``` function if no image is provided? It's never going to emit a value, right?

Comment: I updated the question, as it wasn't describing the scenario that well, please take a look again :)

Comment: But what happens if you don't provide an image and listen to the imageLoaded event? I'm guessing that it emits a "positive" value if an image gets loaded, so in the function in the container you could filter out _negative_ values

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator inside your template statement (event binding) to avoid subscription when there isn't an image :

```
<my-component 
  [headLine]="data.headLine"
  [text]="data.text"
  [image]="data.img"
  (imageLoaded)="data.img ? imageLoaded($event) : 0"
</my-component>
```

Comment: I don't think that avoids a subscription to the `imageLoaded` event. It just has conditional nature in the event handler to not process the event. You could even do this instead of the ternary operator: `data.img && imageLoaded($event)`.